# IOS 5 and TVOUT

Tags: ios, ios5

Lets say I have a iphone 4 with IOS 5. And I have a Apple Digital AV Adapter with a HDMI cable to my beamer.

When I open my app, will my app be displayed on the beamer?

I've read some thing about TVOUT, but im not sure of this is for IOS 5 / iphone 4 also.

Answer (score 0):

It wont be displayed by default, you need to use some libraries for that.

I recommend you this one:

http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/

Ive tried and it works awesome!